# Adding differnet resolution raster layers using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, resolution

I am trying to build a vulnerability index, although I have different resolution raster layers, e.g.: I have a 9km resolution climate change projection on pcp, euclidean distance of roads based on a 30m dem and other polygon layers that I have converted to raster based on my 30m dem.

Can I add these raster layers even though they are different resolution in order to build a vulnerability index?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you will want to resample the rasters with the highest resolution to match the resolution of the lower resolution rasters.

ArcGIS has a [Resample](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/resample.htm) tool that allows you to accomplish this.